# how to add privacy policy in manifest for my app in ms teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to add a text as a privacy policy in the manifest. Where shall I add it in the manifest?
  {

```
  "developer": {
    "name": ,
    "websiteUrl": ,
    "privacyUrl": ,
    "termsOfUseUrl": 
  },

  "description": {

  },


  "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  "validDomains": [
     "contoso.com",
     "token.botframework.com"
  ]
}
```

How can i update this section?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Anu The privacyUrl only accepts a URL. You cannot add a plain text as privacy policy in the manifest.

Comment: @Anu This is a default screen for all the apps on store. This cannot be edited. The actual privacy policies of your app are in the privacyUrl link that you give in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) tool from Microsoft? It's an app that installs directly into Teams itself, to help with various Teams development tasks, and one of these is to provide a nice graphical interface to create and edit your app manifest. In this tool you can capture the url to your privacy policy, wherever it is hosted (to confirm, it does need to be a url to a page hosted somewhere).

In the final manifest, if you do want to edit it by hand rather, it would look something like this:

```
"privacyUrl": "[your web address to your own policy goes here]",
```